# AutoMapper Update Nested Collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, ef-core-2.0

I'm using `AutoMapper` to update my class nested collection along with the other properties, but it throws me the below exception,

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tblEmpLanguages' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

I'm using Swagger to test the API.

**Class:**

```
public class Test : BasicEntity
    {
        public Test()
        {
            this.Languages = new List<Language>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Language> Languages { get; set; }

    }
```

**Basic Entity:**

```
  public class BasicEntity: IEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; } = true;

    }
```

**Mapper:**

```
CreateMap<Test, Test>()
          .ForMember(dest => dest.Languages, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Languages));
```

**Controller (Update Code):**

```
 var dest = _mapper.Map(source, dest);
    _repo.Tests.UpdateTest(dest);
    _repo.Save(); // Exception thrown here
```

**Swagger update:**

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "CreatedDate": "2019-06-26T09:46:51.563Z",
  "CreatedBy": 0,
  "ModifiedDate": "2019-06-26T09:46:51.563Z",
  "ModifiedBy": 0,
  "Active": true,
  "Name": "ABC",
  "Languages": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "CreatedDate": "2019-06-26T09:46:51.563Z",
      "CreatedBy": 0,
      "ModifiedDate": "2019-06-26T09:46:51.563Z",
      "ModifiedBy": 0,
      "Active": true,
      "EmpId": 0,
      "LanguageId": 0,
      "Mothertongue": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to update the Name Property and the Languages list. Where am i wrong and what should i change here?

Comment: Try AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: Not sure that is automapper. Guessing your Language model needs an `[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute.

Comment: @SteveGreene The Basic Entity inherited has the Identity column, i have updated the class in the question now.

Comment: Have you set the [entity state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state) of the child collection (languages) to `EntityState.Modified`? Looks like it is trying to re-add them (EntityState.Added).

Comment: can you add the "Language" class becouse i think that the problem is there for this exception and then you might have another one for the "test" class. basiclly your problem as far as i can see its that you put Id = 1 for the Language element on your json. if it is new item you need it to be 0 and if it exists you need to make sure it is on the table. same with the "test" class becouse you set the column to identity!!!